# XPath select descendent of parents sibling

Tags: php, html, xpath, scrape, siblings

This html is within my page:

```
<tr>
    <td class="padded2" bgcolor="#103A74"><font color="White">Refine by Vehicle Types</font></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td class="padded2" bgcolor="White"><div>
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="padded2"><font color="#103A74"><ul><li><a class="padded2"> Cars</a></li><li><a class="padded2">Marine Engines</a></li><li><a class="padded2">Trucks</a></li></ul></font></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div></td>
</tr>
```

I'm wanting to scrape "Cars" and "Trucks" based on the fact that they are after "Refine by Vehicle Type".
I've tried many diferent ways and this is as close as I can get, but returns NULL.

```
$Nodes = $xPath->query("//tr/td/font[text()[contains(., 'Refine by Vehicle Type')]]/following-sibling::tr/td/div/table/tr/td/font/ul/li/a")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you building this html yourself? Uses classes in one place, and `<font>` tags in another is highly ugly.

Comment: I'm scraping from another site so I cant control the html, its a dynamic page also so I can't just scrape purely based on the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your error is in this**:

```
...font[...]/following-sibling::tr/...
```

It is easy to see that in the provided XML fragment, the `<font>` element has no sibling elements.

**Here is one correct XPath expression**:

```
  tr[td[contains(., 'Refine by Vehicle Types')]]
      /following-sibling::tr
        /td/div/table
                 /tr/td/font
                         /ul/li/a
```

**When evaluated against the following XML document** (your provided fragment wrapped by a `<table>`):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="padded2" bgcolor="#103A74">
            <font color="White">Refine by Vehicle Types</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="padded2" bgcolor="White">
            <div>
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="padded2">
                            <font color="#103A74">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="padded2"> Cars</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="padded2">Marine Engines</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="padded2">Trucks</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**the following elements are selected**:

```
<a class="padded2"> Cars</a>
<a class="padded2">Marine Engines</a>
<a class="padded2">Trucks</a>
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "tr[td[contains(., 'Refine by Vehicle Types')]]
      /following-sibling::tr
        /td/div/table
                 /tr/td/font
                         /ul/li/a
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the XML document above, the selected elements are output**:

```
<a class="padded2"> Cars</a>
<a class="padded2">Marine Engines</a>
<a class="padded2">Trucks</a>
```

**I would recommend using an [XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)** to get quickly up with writing correct and elegant XPath expressions.

Comment: The actual html also contains a duplicate of this html structure with the title "Refine by Category". This xPath scrapes links all the way through and to the end of the document. How can I limit results to this node only?

Comment: @Lictor: Can you, please, clarify your question? Limit to *which* node only?

Comment: Um I ment return matches from the html that I posted ONLY, not all matches that occur after it.

Comment: @Lictor: use: `(//tr[td[contains(., 'Refine by Vehicle Types')]])[1] 
      /following-sibling::tr 
        /td/div/table 
                 /tr/td/font 
                         /ul/li/a `

Comment: humm thats not returning anything... here is the actual html structure I'm working with:
`<tr><td><font color="White">Refine by Vehicle Types</font></td>
 </tr><tr><td><div>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><font><ul><li><a> Automobile/Light Trucks</a></li></ul></font></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div></td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td></td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td><font>Refine by Category</font></td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td><div>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><font><ul><li><a>Agricultural</a></li></ul></font></td></tr>`

Comment: @Lictor: You must provide a complete but minimal XML document so that whether a given expression selects the wanted nodes can be determined -- otherwise even the concpt of "wanted nodes" is undefined. Better, ask a new question and this time formulate it more precisely!